# Why did Arlene need clean blood?

Tags: vampire, true-blood

In the *True Blood* episode *Death is Not the End*, Arlene is mortally wounded.  Sookie seeks to get a vampire to heal her, but she's oddly particular.  She demands a healthy (non-hep-v infected) provide Arlene blood.  This seems weird to me, since

> Arlene's already infected at this point,

and as far as I can recall hep-v infected vampire blood doesn't affect humans differently.

Why did Sookie demand non-hep-v infected blood?

Comment: Maybe infected vampire blood doesn't have healing properties.

Comment: @Jared She already was a carrier.

Comment: It's possibly just an extreme preference in taste or perhaps she is simply germaphobic.